# paginate_links() outputs "paged=" to link instead of "page="

Tags: wordpress, function, pagination, http-status-code-404

I've been having a sever and completely unsolvable problem with pagination.

I did notice however this interesting point:

I search a keyword like cute:

```
?s=cute&submit=Search&post_type=image&paged=2
```

...is where the link leads to. **"Paged="** gives 404 on random pages. But if I modify the URL to say **page=**

```
?s=cute&submit=Search&post_type=image&page=2
```

Every page destination works, bringing joy to my heart, but the pagination tab list always sticks at 0 (not reflecting current page).

I feel like I'm playing a "shell game" with code and settings, with wordpress bamboozling me.

**Question reduces to:**

How can I get `&page=` to be output in every case? Conversely, if `&paged=` should be the way it goes, how do I get it to work without 404s?!?!

This is a problem I've dealt with for almost 3 months now. People are shy to answer.

---

**update:**

Trying to deal with this `paged` variable in the URL which breaks pagination, I created a filter to simply replace it with `page`.

```
function symbiostock_pagination_mod( $args ){

    $args = str_replace('paged=', 'page=', $args);

    return $args;
    }

add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'symbiostock_pagination_mod', 1 );
```

Would seem like a great idea! But then this happens with every new click:

```
?s=cute&post_type=image&page=2&page=2

?s=cute&post_type=image&page=2&page=3
```

So where is this being modded, and why?

---

**update:**

I'm not sure if I'm the only one that has ever had this problem, but I did solve it (at least for myself) you can see the solution below. Also thanks for the help given. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what I came up with...we might as well call it a **hack** or **work-around** because its unknown if this was indeed a bug I'm dealing with (from wordpress itself) or just a perfectly hidden problem in my theme's code.

The below function filters the '`paginate_links()`' function and achieves this:

1. I see `paged` variable generates 404 randomly on *search* pages, but works fine on *archive* and *taxonomy* pages. So, we check that. `if_search()`, we do our changes...
2. If this is a search, we get the would-be page # destination using regex (or simply string replace `paged` to `page`, depending on permalink structure. We use `remove_query_var()` to drop faulty variable, and `add_query_var()` to put the working one.

   This is being done because in this strange case, `page` always generates proper results.
3. Then we return the edited destination link, and life is good.

Function below:

```
add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'my_search_pagination_mod', 1 );

function my_search_pagination_mod( $link )
{

    if ( is_search() ) {
        
        $pattern = '/page\/([0-9]+)\//';
        
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $link, $matches ) ) {
            $number = $matches[ 1 ];
            
            $link = remove_query_arg( 'paged' );
            
            $link = add_query_arg( 'page', $number );
            
        } else {
            
            $link = str_replace( 'paged', 'page', $link );
            
        }
        
    }

    return $link;
}
```

---

Also thanks to some help I got here with the regular expression: [PHP Regular Expression Help: A quick way to extract the 2 from "page/2/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227524/php-regular-expression-help-a-quick-way-to-extract-the-2-from-page-2)

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted your question and answer. One day I might need to use this hack of yours:)