# PHP Regular Expression Help: A quick way to extract the 2 from "page/2/"

Tags: php, regex, find, expression

Regular expressions - my current Achilles heal.

I just need a way to take the string "`page/2/`" and extract the number, and only the number. It will always take that format.

So could be `page/2/` to `page/999999/`.

This is what I currently have:

```
preg_match_all('/\/page\/.*\//', 'page/2/', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

How would this be done?

Comment: This is the basic level regex. Please take some time to learn it yourself.

Comment: As a general rule I don't post here unless I've tried and could not make it work.

Comment: Post what you have tried, then. I can't see this as different than any other "give me the codez" post.

Comment: Sure, if it matters that much to you: preg_match_all('/\/page\/.*\//', 'page/2/', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); ---- for whatever its worth, that was the final step in a 3 month problem I've dealt with, and will be crediting this page :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround the pattern by a self-choosen delimiter `#`, search for `page/`, use a special matching group `()` to get the number `[0-9]`, use the `+` to get at least 1 or more digits:

```
$pattern = '#page/([0-9]+)#';
if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

If you want to learn more, you should have a look at the [PCRE pattern syntax manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) on the PHP website.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was far off.

Comment: If it's from a URL, I'd be using `parse_url()` but we don't know that much...

Comment: Yep! the comment of @nickhar should being noted

Comment: or $pattern = '#page/\K\d++(?=/)#';

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nice one! Why not answering this?